# How to display class diagram in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get a class diagram in VS Code, something like the one you can obtain in IntelliJ.

Do you have any idea if it is possible?

Comment: Maybe there's a language-specific extension. VS Code is a generic editor used for _any_ kind of language, so it's highly unlikely that there's a built-in feature.

Comment: To make this question more specific, please specify the programming language.

Comment: IntelliJ is java - if you're referring to Java please tag it